# showing the end of a textfield

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bunch of textfields which identical starting data, the first 2 dozen characters are all the same for every input.

The end is different.

How do I get the textfield to scroll right automatically to show the end by default?

Comment: where is the code?? read [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input?

Comment: it might help to actually post the html for that form here. :)

Comment: What do you mean code, it's just an input type="textfield"

Comment: @el toni yeah, thanks If you post it as an answer i'll mark it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@el toni has a great solution.  However, the `textfield` won't function properly if the user is required to input any text.  (The cursor will jump to the left.)

```
<input dir="rtl" value="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input">
```

(*Above from ["Scroll" to the very right of a long text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input) courtesy @el toni)

You could use some `js` so that when the user clicks on the field, the "right direction" for text input is re-established.  Then change it back to the other direction after he/she clicks off.

```
 $("#longInput").focus(function () {
     $(this).attr('dir', 'ltr');
});
 $("#longInput").blur(function () {
     $(this).attr('dir', 'rtl');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjjL2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the scrollTo javascript function:

```
var myTextfield = document.getElementById("myTextfield");
myTextfield.scrollTop = myTextfield.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: There's no height. Just width

Comment: the scrollHeight is not the containers height, its just the measurement of how much height you are able to show by scrolling. and besides i think that all textfealds have a default height.