# how to change negative sign position css

Tags: html, css, negative-number

I have a web site that shows its content it two direction. rtl & ltr.

When page is in ltr content mode, every thins is OK and the negative sign shows in the left of number.

```
body {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

> For example: -1

But when page is in rtl mode,

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

the negative sign of numbers shows in the right of number.

> For example: 1-

Whereas I want to show negative sign in the left of number in both cases. How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Wrap numbers and change css direction?

Comment: as above, a span should do!

Comment: You can also try to prepend numbers with [left-to-right-mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm), as answered [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227183/rtl-is-on-web-page-reverses-numbers-with-a-dash#19930251)

Comment: That's right @skobaljic. It worked with adding span and then, change direction and FINALLY change display to inline-block. pls, answer this question til I marked as answer. Thanks.

Comment: You did it yourself, you can also answer it and I shall upvote, cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the number in span and add two  following css to it:

```
direction: ltr;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: why ltr is not enough?

Answer (score 3):

Check the code below!

```css
BODY {
    direction: rtl;
}
#test {
    direction: ltr;   
    text-align: right
}
```

```html
    Sample Text abc <br />
    -1
    <p id="test">-1 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the numbers in a `span` and changing the direction didn't seem to have any effect, as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/kLpa8ygv/.

However, the OP found that by adding `inline-block` and writing the `-` in the span, the solution worked. Just adding it to this answer so it can be as resourceful as possible. Please check comments and OP's answer for full details.

```
direction: ltr;
display: inline-block;
```

You could always resort to a little JavaScript to fix the problem. Use this script to detect whether body is rtl and change accordingly (assuming ltr is the default in the HTML):

```
var element = document.body,
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    direction = style.getPropertyValue('direction');

if (direction == "rtl") {
    document.getElementById("neg").innerHTML = "1-";
}
```

The full code is in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/axpevvon/4/

Answer (score 1):

we also support both direction in our website and with a lot of numbers. I have found this to be cleaner because there are cases we do not want to change: `display: inline-block;` property

solution:

```
div {
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_unicode-bidi.asp for more about properties and options

Answer (score 1):

**This can be used**

```
body {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}
```

[Refer this mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi)

Answer (score 0):

You can give number in span and give that span direction to ltr like:

```
<span class="nagativeVal">-1</span>
```

**css:**

```
.nagativeVal
{
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Hope it helps.