# Why does inline-block change rtl ordering?

Tags: html, css, unicode

Thanks Jax-p for linking me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227183/rtl-is-on-web-page-reverses-numbers-with-a-dash).  It shows more correct ways of dealing with this issue.  I still don't know why inline-block is working the way it is, though.

I have an Electron app showing data transfer for different users and a limit on total transfer,
like this

```html
<span>
  1 MB / 2 GB
</span>
```

However, in rtl languages this shows up strangely:

```html
<span dir="rtl">
  1 MB / 2 GB
</span>
```

I stumbled upon a solution using `inline-block` styling

```css
#c > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span id="c" dir="rtl">
  <span> 1 MB </span>
  &nbsp; / &nbsp;
  <span> 2 GB </span>
</span>
```

This works, but I don't understand why.  RTL users are a decent portion of my user base and so I don't want to throw a hack in I don't understand.  Is this just a happy accident or is there something deeper about inline block styling that I don't understand?

Note: This doesn't work if I don't put the individual components in separate spans -- if the parent span is given `inline-block` styling it doesn't change the display order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RTL is on web page reverses numbers with a dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227183/rtl-is-on-web-page-reverses-numbers-with-a-dash)

Comment: That helps a lot!  A lot of better solutions there. 

I'm still curious why the inline-block solution worked as well, though

Answer (score 1):

You second example works due to the nature of `inline-block` elements. They are inline level elements but create block container. In other words, they create an isolated world that cannot interact with the outside.

The direction property will work inside both `inline-block` element separately so there is no interaction between their content.

The main steps are as follow:

1. apply the direction algorithm inside each `inline-block` elements
2. apply the direction algorithm between both `inline-block` elements

Without `inline-block`, the whole text will be considered in the same direction algorithm

To better illustrate the isolation:

```css
#c > span {
  display: inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}

#c {
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="c" >
  <span style="background:red;"> </span>
  <span style="background:blue;"> </span>
</div>

<div id="c" dir="rtl">
  <span style="background:red;"> </span>
  <span style="background:blue;"> </span>
</div>
```

The above illustrate the step 2

And the below the step 1

```css
#c > span {
  display: inline-block;
}

#c {
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="c" >
  <span >1 MB </span>
</div>

<div id="c" dir="rtl">
  <span >1 MB </span>
</div>
```