# "scroll" to the end of the input after js modifies input's value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<input id="inp" type="text">` that user writes in, and sometimes uses suggests from a dictionary. When a suggest is selected I do:

```
var input = $('#inp'); 
input.val(input.val()+suggestedText+' '); 
input.focus(); // that is because the suggest can be selected with mouse
```

everything works great, but when after adding a suggest that makes the resulting `input.val()` too long to fit in the edit field, the cursor is at the end of the string (which is good), but only the beginning of the string is visible in the edit field, so the cursor is hidden as well.

As soon as a key is pressed (a key that changes the value) the "scroll" goes to the end of the string hiding the beginning... How to trigger this behavior automatically, without having to press a key?

I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input) - but it is not good as the whole input experience is changed...

Comment: is this what you need?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you need to set the focus() **BEFORE** you set the value. You can fix this in many ways, for example:

```
input.focus(); // that is because the suggest can be selected with mouse
var input = $('#inp'); 
input.val(input.val() + suggestedText + ' ');
```

Or this one:

```
function changeValue(element, newValue) {
    element.focus();
    element.val(element.val() + newValue + ' ');
}
```

Comment: it didn't help done your way... it already had focus 'cause event fired came from keyboard within the input field... I had to blur, and then focus to make this work... take a look at the example I provided below...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
var input = $('#inp'); 
input.val(input.val()+suggestedText+' '); 
input.focus(); // that is because the suggest can be selected with mouse

var height=input.contents()[0].outerHeight()
input.animate({
    scrollTop:height
},'normal');
```

?

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for answers, meanwhile I have found sth as well... 
when using mouse to click the input lost focus (clik on sth else), and then regained it (thanks to input.focus()) - "scrolling" to the end, but when choosing a suggest was done with a keyboard, focus was never lost, and that is why it was not "scrolling" itself. I just simply added input.blur(), before input.focus(), now works like a charm... have a look at working example

```
http://46.4.128.78/input/
```