# focus html in the end of a input text (not only cursor)

Tags: javascript, html, web

Lot's of solutions here on stackoverflow show how to focus the cursor at the end of an input text but they don't show how to **focus visually** the end of a input text - the overflow of an input text.

Ex:

Most of the solutions are focus at the end but show the start of the text:

[image]

[image]

But via javascript, I want to focus the end:

[image]

Edit:

Not duplicate because

```
dir="rtl"
```

doesn't solve it. I want to fill the field left to write, but when click on it I want to scroll to the end of the input text. @ibiza's answer solved the problem.

Comment: See here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfkhio.php

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Scroll" to the very right of a long text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input)

Comment: yes, possible duplicate, **and** the answer here from ibiza is an exact copy of [Lucman Abdulrachman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2031863/lucman-abdulrachman)'s answer on that other question.

Comment: @StephenP yeah, that's true. should I delete my question? That solves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#myInput').get(0).scrollLeft = $('#myInput').get(0).scrollWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below

```
<input type="text" id="search" value="Some People like cupcake better" />
<script>
document.getElementById("search").scrollLeft = document.getElementById("search").scrollWidth; 
</script>
```

DEMO: [LINK](http://hangupin.com/editor/?id=5512f343cb993)

Hope this helps you