# How to anchor text field text to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of fields forming line items and the fields text are aligned to the right currently. In most cases it works fine, however when the number exceeds the input width then the text/numbers are displayed from left to right. While it is an extreme case, I'm wondering if there is a way to always anchor the field text to the right.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1962168/1059070

Comment: If you use the information at the link above, please read the comments below the selected answer. Misusing the `dir` attribute has side effects. Consider using the second or third answer as a guide.

Comment: thanks @arcyqwerty and @george Cummins, the `dir` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Poyi Good luck. Be sure to watch what happens when you type a character such as `.` or backslash ('\'). This appears to be an integer-only input, so you may get away with it (at least temporarily).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment. The solution in stackoverflow.com/q/1962168/1059070 is what I was looking for.