# How to move view "to the current caret position" within an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a Mobile AngularJS App, where in a certain case i have to set the text in input field manually and set the focus in this input field again, in order user can type further.

The problem is, when the text length is bigger than the input width, i do not see the end of text on my viewport, but the beginning. when i type further the viewport immediatelly shows me the end of text again (where the caret is). So the caret is in the correct position (end of text), focus is also set correctly.

But how can i immediately show the end of string or caret position in the input field after a manual change?

Here is how this works in Google Mobile Suggestion List. I click the top-left-arrow icon

[image]

.. and the suggestion is taken in input field. And we see the cursor, which is at the end of text.

[image]

In my case after setting the new text and setting the focus in input, i have this view:

[image]

Comment: Can you mimic a space bar click after the focus. I have not tried it but it may work.

Comment: did not really work

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input this might help

Comment: thanks it solved it!