# How can I cause the text to overflow to the left of my text input?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an input field (of variable width) with text which is longer than it can display. By default, it shows the leftmost section of the string (i.e. the first part of the string) and hides the excess (the rightmost part, i.e. the end of the string).

```html
<input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" style="width: 25%; font-size: 25px; margin: 50px;">
```

[image: input by default cutting off the end of the string]

When one clicks in the input field, one can move the window, and view any part of the string. When the cursor is at the end of the string, only the end section is displayed - the first part of the string is cut off, and hidden:

[image: text when focused with cursor at the end]

I want the input field to always look like this, by preferring to cut off the front of the string, rather than the end (simply because for this specific input the end of the string is more useful to see than the start).

Using `text-align: right` unfortunately doesn't achieve this - it only causes the text to be right aligned when the full text can fit:

[image: text which can all fit, and is then right aligned]

I'd rather not use JS to cut the length of the string, as this would prevent the user being able to edit it.

---

To be clear, I would like this to happen all the time, rather than only when it's focused via [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Comment: If it is on focus you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thanks, yeah. I'd quite like it to be all the time (even when not focused) although I've implemented that one as a halfway-house.

Comment: I think you might have to implement a content editable div that way you can control its alignment. I don't think you can do it with a normal text field.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you are looking for use a [content editable div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content). With it you can use `justify-content` with `flexbox`.

```css
div[type=text] {
  /* Scroll to the end */
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: inline-flex;
  
  /* Basic display formatting */
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div type="text" contenteditable="true">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
```

If you don't like the right alignment, we can remove the flexbox and use javascript to align the items:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div[type=text]')].forEach(el => {
  el.scrollLeft = el.scrollWidth;
})
```

```css
div[type=text] {
  /* Basic display formatting */
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div type="text" contenteditable="true">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" style="width: 25%; font-size: 25px; margin: 50px;" dir="rtl" onfocus="this.dir='auto';this.scrollLeft = this.scrollWidth;" onfocusout="this.scrollLeft = this.scrollWidth;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the Solution,You have to add a class name to apply css.

```
<input type="text" class="myclass" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" style="width: 
25%; font-size: 25px; margin: 50px;">
```

The CSS

```
.myclass{
direction: rtl;
text-align: left;

}
```

Comment: This changes the arrow key direction, and also seems to get mixed up when a string starts with `/`

Comment: I Understood the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ["Scroll" to the very right of a long text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input)

With scrollWidth:

```html
<input style="width: 100px" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
<input style="width: 100px" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
<input style="width: 100px" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
```

```js
$('input').each(function(){ $(this).scrollLeft($(this)[0].scrollWidth) })
```

As tim said, dir attribute is not a good solution with caracters '<' '>' '/' '\'

Comment: With the input style the only issue I see is that once you remove focus it scrolls back to the beginning. With rtl the text is right aligned.