# Showing last part of input text when it is not on focus any more?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the case of input whenever we focus out or click outside the input field we see that the right part of the over text is hidden and only the left part shows but I want the reverse of it.

```html
<input value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz123456789">
```

Like in the above input field we can see "abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz1" and the rest part("23456789") is hidden but I want to show "klmnopqrstwxyz123456789" (last part instead of the first part) and hide the first part "abcdefghij" without CSS direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Scroll" to the very right of a long text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962168/scroll-to-the-very-right-of-a-long-text-input)

Comment: *.....without CSS direction*......why?

Comment: @Mamun Because whenever I add symbols like + or ".". it starts showing them at the very first place when the text-direction is right. Like if I will text "45+" then it will show "+46"

Comment: @SSKhekhaliya, Does this solve your issue? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/bGrzWBe

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yeah, this is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via javascript, we can achieve it with the help of [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event.

On blur, we capture the input's current [`Element.scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) . Next, we reset the scrollLeft position to [`Element.scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) wrapped in a `setTimeout()` to ensure the browser waits to render the queued change.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('data');

elem.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    elem.scrollLeft = elem.scrollWidth;
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<input id="data" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz123456789">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code - for dynamically change the length of your text on changing the content

```
function a (t){
    t.size = t.value.length
    console.log(t)
}

<input onkeyup="a(this)" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz123456789">
```

Comment: No no, it changes the width of the input field. I didn't want to change it.