# Focus Input Box On Load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

How can the cursor be focus on a specific input box on page load?

Is it posible to retain initial text value as well and place cursor at end of input?

```
<input type="text"  size="25" id="myinputbox" class="input-text" name="input2" value = "initial text" />
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

There are two parts to your question.

**1) How to focus an input on page load?**

You can just add the `autofocus` attribute to the input.

```
<input id="myinputbox" type="text" autofocus>
```

However, this might not be supported in all browsers, so we can use javascript.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myinputbox").focus();
}
```

**2) How to place cursor at the end of the input text?**

Here's a non-jQuery solution with some borrowed code from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1675345/5651).

```
function placeCursorAtEnd() {
  if (this.setSelectionRange) {
    // Double the length because Opera is inconsistent about 
    // whether a carriage return is one character or two.
    var len = this.value.length * 2;
    this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
  } else {
    // This might work for browsers without setSelectionRange support.
    this.value = this.value;
  }

  if (this.nodeName === "TEXTAREA") {
    // This will scroll a textarea to the bottom if needed
    this.scrollTop = 999999;
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myinputbox");

  if (obj.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener("focus", placeCursorAtEnd, false);
  } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent('onfocus', placeCursorAtEnd);
  }

  input.focus();
}
```

Here's an example of how I would accomplish this with jQuery.

```
<input type="text" autofocus>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("[autofocus]").on("focus", function() {
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
      var len = this.value.length * 2;
      this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
    } else {
      this.value = this.value;
    }
    this.scrollTop = 999999;
  }).focus();
});
</script>
```

Comment: The first code block suggested actually places the cursor at the end of the existing value as well, it works good. I apreciate your help.

Comment: The Javascript version is very good, works flawless for iframe with autofocus issues.  Also lightweight and compact.  +1 as it helped me.

Answer (score 56):

Just a heads up - you can now do this with HTML5 without JavaScript for browsers that support it:

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

You probably want to start with this and build onto it with JavaScript to provide a fallback for older browsers.

Comment: Nice to know that, does this already moves the cursor to the last position in the input field?

Comment: I don't think that @Codex73 is trying to accomplish what the placeholder attribute in HTML5 does. It sounds like he wants the cursor to be automatically positioned at the end of whatever value is currently in the input.

Comment: You're right, this isn't a complete solution.  But this does solve a couple of things (onload autofocus and placeholder text).

Comment: Note that as of 1/2019, Safari on iOS does not support this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus

Answer (score 12):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id').focus();
});
```

Comment: This requires jQuery.

Comment: Yeah you need to include jQuery libs :)

Comment: classic stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function focusOnMyInputBox(){                                 
    document.getElementById("myinputbox").focus();
}

<body onLoad="focusOnMyInputBox();">

<input type="text"  size="25" id="myinputbox" class="input-text" name="input2" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" value = "initial text">
```

Answer (score 2):

A portable way of doing this is using a custom function (to handle browser differences) like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element/1675345#1675345).

Then setup a handler for the `onload` at the end of your `<body>` tag, as jessegavin wrote:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myinputbox").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

very simple one line solution:

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('myinputbox').focus();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fine...

```
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myinputbox").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

**Javascript Pure:**

```
[elem][n].style.visibility='visible';
[elem][n].focus();
```

**Jquery:**

```
[elem].filter(':visible').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works fine for me:

```
<form name="f" action="/search">
    <input name="q" onfocus="fff=1" />
</form>
```

fff will be a global variable which name is absolutely irrelevant and which aim will be to stop the generic onload event to force focus in that input.

```
<body onload="if(!this.fff)document.f.q.focus();">
    <!-- ... the rest of the page ... -->
</body>
```

From: http://webreflection.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/inputfocus-something-really-annoying.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add to the BODY tag for some reason, you can add this AFTER the Form:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    document.yourFormName.yourFieldName.focus();
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your js

```
var input = $('#myinputbox');

input.focus();
```

Or to html

```
<script>
    var input = $('#myinputbox');

    input.focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it!

```
window.onload = function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  document.getElementById("input-box-id").focus();
  document.getElementById("input-box-id").click();
 }, 1000);
}
```