# HTML search form allow input text immediately

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Focus Input Box On Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331022/focus-input-box-on-load)

i need a  HTML search form that allow input text immediately. Same as Google. we needn't click to input text into search form

Comment: That is not clear HTML. You need javascript.

Comment: thanks you. are you have yahoo chat id? i want to learn more from you

Comment: When you have enough rep, you can use the SO chat rooms. I think it's 50 rep?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be achieved a few different ways. The easiest would be via a AJAX POST via jquery. I'll give you a little example:

Let's pretend your search input has a name attribute such as "keywords"

```
$(function(){  
  $("input[name='keywords']").keyup(function(){
    $(".search_results").slideUp("normal", function(){
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST", url: "searchquery.php", 
        data: {keywords: $(this).val()},
        success: function(response){
          if(response != "error")
          {
            $(".search_results").html(response);
            $(".search_results").slideDown();
          }
          else
          {
            alert("Error Searching. Please refresh the page and try again.");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Then you need to have searchquery.php handle searching the database and returning the data in html format. Maybe something like this:

```
if(trim($_POST["keywords"]) != "")
{
  $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["keywords"]);

  //search the DB for maybe 5 top results and return them in something like a HTML list:
  $results = '<ul><li>first</li><li>second</li></ul>';

  die($results);
}
```

Your on your own for formatting the div or HTML object with the class "search_results" defined on it.

Also, I would advise adding a timer, so that each time the "keyup" function is hit, it records the time and make a minimum of **_** amount of time before the next call to the file is allowed. That way the PHP file doesn't get 5 calls when someone writes 1 word.