# Why is window.onload function undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, onload

I have made a simple function and it is supposed to run on window.onload. But instead, I get that it is undefined. Can anyone help me understand why I get this error?

The form id is kalkulator and the name of the inputs is liter and enheter

The function I have written is

```
window.onload = function () {
    form.kalkulator.focus();
};
```

I have also written this

```
form.kalkulator = function () {
    if (form.enheter.value == "") {
        form.liter.value = "";
    } else{
        convertLiter();
    };
}

function convertLiter() {
    console.log(form.liter.value / person.volum() * person.sukker_g())
    form.enheter.value = form.liter.value / person.volum();

}
function convertEnheter() {
    console.log(form.enheter.value * person.sukker_g())
    form.liter.value = form.enheter.value * person.volum();
}
```

Comment: you missed the form initialization var form = {};

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4331028/2180252

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `window.onload`.

You're invoking this...

```
form.kalkulator.focus();
```

but `form.kalkulator` is a *function*, it doesn't have a `.focus()` method. `form.klalkulator.focus` is undefined, and you're attempting to invoke it as a function, hence your error.

Comment: @user262669 Don't write that line of code. I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

form.kalkulator doesn't have any return so you can't call

```
  form.kalkulator.focus();
```

replace the function

```
form.kalkulator = function () {
    if (form.enheter.value == "") {
        form.liter.value = "";
    } else{
        convertLiter();
   };
return form;
}
```

or split the instructions;

```
form.kalkulator();
form.focus();
```