# Focus Input Box On Key Pressed

Tags: javascript, html, onfocus

I have created a live search, I want when user clicks on ESC it should focus to input box and remove its content if not empty automatically.

I am able to remove the content but it won't focus on key press.

The function `focus();` works when I use it on `window.onload`

I have the existing code: (also tried the ones maked in comment thanks to [Focus Input Box On Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331022/focus-input-box-on-load), and [JavaScript set focus to HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/javascript-set-focus-to-html-form-element))

```
var aramaAlani = document.getElementById("id_arama");

$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { //ESC key code
        aramaAlani.reset();
        aramaAlani.focus();     
        //aramaAlani.scrollIntoView();
        //document.forms[ 'id_arama' ].elements[ _element ].focus();
        //document.getElementById("id_search").focus();
    }
});
```

Is there any specific method for key events to focus on element?

Comment: $(document) check this and add the id or class or element

Comment: Is this script in the `head` or in the bottom of the `body`?

Comment: @MoshFeu Its located in the `head`.

Comment: So, you need to move it to the bottom of the body, or wrap it with `$(document).ready`. More info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328449/when-do-you-put-javascript-in-body-when-in-head-and-when-use-doc-load

Comment: @MoshFeu, Thanks for prompt reply. I have tried to move it or wrap it with `$(document).ready` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `clear` function on `input`.

You have 2 options:

**Clear the specific input** using `input.value = '';`

Like this:

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="id_arama" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var aramaAlani = document.getElementById("id_arama");

    $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
      if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { //ESC key code
        //form.reset();
        aramaAlani.value = '';
        aramaAlani.focus();     
        //aramaAlani.scrollIntoView();
        //document.forms[ 'id_arama' ].elements[ _element ].focus();
        //document.getElementById("id_search").focus();
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

**Or you can use the method `reset()`** but you can call it only on `form` element. The good point in this solution is if you want to clear many inputs.

Like this:

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="id_arama" />
  </form>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var aramaAlani = document.getElementById("id_arama");

    $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
      if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { //ESC key code
        form.reset();
        aramaAlani.focus();     
        //aramaAlani.scrollIntoView();
        //document.forms[ 'id_arama' ].elements[ _element ].focus();
        //document.getElementById("id_search").focus();
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation. I have everything the same but it still does not work on mine.I covered my `<input>` with `<fieldset>` right after `<form>`. Do I have to update the querySelector?

Comment: Nope.. The `querySelector` should cover it too. Can you create a working snippet or bin with your code so I could try to understand what's wrong with it?

Comment: This is the full version: https://jsfiddle.net/k7a7suj9/ , search  javascript side doesnt included since it doesnt work on jsfiddle for some reason.

Comment: I was fixed the fiddle. There were jquery references problem. Also, you changed the `id ` of the input from `id_arama` to ``. https://jsfiddle.net/k7a7suj9/2/