# selecting an input (to type) from start

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an app to do some calculating to the input number that i enter, i want the website to select the input field to enter the values as soon as website loads.

to make it clearer, I want the field selected by default and ready to type and don't have to select the field with mouse click.

Comment: On page load, find the element and call `element.focus()`.

Comment: It would be much more clear with a [mcve]. Please [edit] the post and include the relevant parts of the code you're having issue with

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331022/focus-input-box-on-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 inputs support the `autofocus` attribute :

`<input type="text" autofocus>`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp