# How can I put focus on a field after the entered text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Focus After Last Character in Text Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609405/set-focus-after-last-character-in-text-box)

I have a text field that has a default value in it. I would like to use jquery to focus on this field, but using `focus()` puts the cursor before the text that's already entered. How can I focus the cursor after the entered text?

Comment: just flagged it for duplicate on that one too

Answer (score 1):

You can set the caret position like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tSChT/.

```
var textbox = $("#textbox");

textbox.prop("selectionStart", textbox.val().length) // set caret to length (end)
       .focus();
```