# Control where typing starts in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to control where in an input typing starts on focus?

e.g.

```
<input type="text" value="(+44)" id="phone_number" />
```

I need the user's typing to begin after the existing value, but leave the option to backspace and delete.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#phone_number').focus(function(){
  //place type start after whatever value already exists
 });
});
```

Comment: This could be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4609476/1551411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, you can do:

```
$("input").focus(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val("");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.val(val);
    }, 1);
});
```

Taken from this [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805277/1479606).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jJZuh/)**

Answer (score 1):

This can also help you to keep formatted input field

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
 jQuery(function($){
    $("#phone_number").mask("(+44)999999");
 });
```

I have use 9 to add only numeric values only, else you can you * to add anything