# Set focus and cursor to end of text input field / string w. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following function that adds a selector to a search input as an advanced option, just like stack overflows advanced search.

When you click what you are searching for it adds a prefix. See Jquery below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("table#advanced_search_options tr").click(function () {
            var SearchSelection = $(this).children("td:last-of-type").html();
            var SearchInput = $('#Search');
            SearchInput.val(SearchInput.val() + SearchSelection);
            return false;
            alert(SearchSelection);
        });
});
</script>
```

How can I manipulate the above to also bring focus to the #search input, placing the carrot (the blinking text insert cursor) to the end of the inserted text/value?
eg.

HC:  <-- The added value to my search input, I would like to set the cursor here, right after the :

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can do this using [`Input.setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange), part of the Range API for interacting with text selections and the text cursor:

```
var searchInput = $('#Search');

// Multiply by 2 to ensure the cursor always ends up at the end;
// Opera sometimes sees a carriage return as 2 characters.
var strLength = searchInput.val().length * 2;

searchInput.focus();
searchInput[0].setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ayrd/)

Comment: Just in case: `if (newEl.attr('type') != 'number') {}` prevents you from trying to set the caret on input-types that do not support setting the caret

Comment: see this fork: `http://jsfiddle.net/msLkp1gt/1/`, I want user to focus on first and when they use tab to focus on second, cursor should go to end.

Comment: You should multiply the value length by 2 because Opera sometimes sees a carriage return as 2 characters. Hence the text being selected not at the end every time.

Comment: This did not work for me! I wrapped it in a `setTimeout(function() { //code }, 0);`

Comment: as @DerkJanSpeelman mentioned, for me it had to be wrapped inside a setTimeout of 0