# .focus() - how to put the curser at end of content using contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Afternoon,

I have a content editible div which, after appending some images too after uploaded, I wish to be focused the user can continue typing without having to click back into the div.

To my surprise,

```
.focus();
```

Works, but puts the curser at the start of the text, any way to put the curser at the end?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxtasnbL/

Backup code:

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>

var div = $(".textarea");
div.append('Some text before an image <br><img class="temp_added_image" src="http://www.deshow.net/d/file/car/2010-10/seat-electric-car-879-2.jpg"><br><br>');
div.focus();
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568041/set-focus-and-cursor-to-end-of-text-input-field-string-w-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using a selection range that starts at where you want the caret to be:

```
var sel = window.getSelection(), range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
range.setStartBefore(div.children().last()[0]);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/mxtasnbL/2/