# How to fix cursor position when prevent browser's default paste action

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, range, rich-text-editor

There is a custom method to insert HTML(**html fragment not just plain text**) into an editor (Rich Text Editor), but for some reason I have to use `e.preventDefault` to prevent browser default paste action and insert the copy data later. My code looks like below:

```
editor.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
   var data = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html'),
       newData;
   e.preventDefault();
   newData = custom.handle(data);
   custom.insert(newData);
}, false);
```

After `custom.insert(newData)`, cursor is still blinking at the origin position. I expected it to have moved the end of `newData`.

Can anybody help me fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set focus and cursor to end of text input field / string w. Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568041/set-focus-and-cursor-to-end-of-text-input-field-string-w-jquery)

Comment: @PedroMendes Eh..., actually the pasted data maybe a html fragment, as we paste data into a iframe that has ```contentEditable``` attribute instead of ```input``` or ```textarea```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what properties of functions your `custom` has, but you can use this the code to move the cursor to the end of the text in an `input` and `textarea`:

```
custom.selectionStart = custom.selectionEnd;
```

If `newData` is pasted in the middle or beginning of the text, then you will have to calculate the length of `newData` and move the cursor by that many characters. Something like:

```
custom.selectionStart = custom.selectionStart + newData.length;
custom.selectionEnd = custom.selectionStart;
```

**Edit to answer your question:** How to calculate the length of text with HTML tags?

Well, this will be a bit tricky. You can create a temporary HTML element in memory, add the `newData` in it, and calculate the length of its `innerText` property. Something like this:

```
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = newData;
custom.selectionStart = custom.selectionStart + temp.innerText.length;
custom.selectionEnd = custom.selectionStart;
```

Note: `innerText` is was introduced by Microsoft and is not a W3C standard. The implementation varies across browsers although most replicate IE's behavior. `innerText` is style-aware and will only return the visible text.

Comment: In my case, the pasted data maybe a html fragment, it seems that we can't just calculate the ```newData.length```...

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean, but the data will be pasted in is a iframe that has ```contentEditable``` attribute, How can I implement ```setSelectionRange``` method?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `setSelectionRange` because you're not really selecting, you're just moving the cursor. And you still need to know where the cursor currently is, so you still need `selectionStart`. Try this: `custom.setSelectionRange(custom.selectionStart + temp.innerText.length, custom.selectionStart + temp.innerText.length);`. Obviously, it is better to put the value `custom.selectionStart + temp.innerText.length` into a variable instead of repeating it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your question may already have an answer here:

[Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

[Set focus and cursor to end of text input field / string w. Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568041/set-focus-and-cursor-to-end-of-text-input-field-string-w-jquery)

With Mike Berrow's example, you can replace the input value with itself to set the carret to the end of the input. This would seem to be the most reliable way to do it, event if it is slightly hackish.

```
myInput.value = myInput.value;
```

With browsers that support it, you can rather use the setSelectionRange method. Since you already use clipboardData, this shouldn't be a problem.

```
myInput.setSelectionRange(myInput.value.length, myInput.value.length);
```

Pay attention to the fact that the value length may be harder to get if you are working with a textarea.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

Comment: It seems that the ```setSelectionRange``` works fine with text, but what if ```newData``` is a html fragment? In that case we can't calculate the  length of pasted data :(