# Javascript how to place cursor at end of input field text after inserting text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field and after a tab or enter keydown event some text is filled into the input field. How do I then make the cursor be at the end of the text that was filled?

This is the html:

```
<input name="author" type="text" id="author"></input>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var authorInput = document.getElementById("author");
authorInput.value = authorName;
authorInput.innerHTML = authorName;
```

where `authorName` is a string like "example".  Now after setting the innerHTML I want the cursor to be at the end of the text in the input field. How do I do this?

I prefer no jquery but am open to it if it is a much "better" solution.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/emk00ehs/2/) is a jsfiddle example with an attempt at solving it, which does not work. I want the div's click event handler to make the cursor be at the end of the input text when it is done running.

Comment: You can handle default values and cursor autofocus in the HTML. Don't need javascript.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate because its not an onfocus event. The input is already focused. I will try it right now though.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes i just tried using onfocus and it did not work. I'm looking through the other javascript solutions to see if that helps

Comment: There are more answers than the accepted answer. For instance, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10576409/215552) doesn't mention focus and shows how to set the selection manually. There are also other duplicates, like http://stackoverflow.com/q/19568041/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/499126/215552...

Comment: Input tags close themselves, so what you have doesn't make sense. You can't write to the inside of a tag if there isn't an inside.

Comment: @Waxi you're right but it doesn't affect anything to have the innerHTML there. I delted it but still the question is the same