# How to show cursor position of text box to second letter on page load asp .net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

On selecting dropdown list a value is displayed on the textbox but the cursor position is on the beginning of textbox. But I need to show it after the value on the textbox.

```
protected void drgBranches_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        txtLoginName.Text = drgBranches.SelectedValue;
        txtLoginName.Focus();
    }
```

It works fine in google chrome and IE. But it doesn't work on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using just *jQuery* :

```
$('#txtLoginName').focus();
$('#txtLoginName').val($('#txtLoginName').val())
```

---

Check this post [Set Focus After Last Character in Text Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609405/set-focus-after-last-character-in-text-box) where is different examples how to do this, but this one is the easiest.

---

Update for FF :

To make it work in FF firstly clear textBox value and then set it again

```
    var val = $('#txtLoginName').val();
    $('#txtLoginName').val('');
    $('#txtLoginName').val(val);
```

Live Example : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93r68f8b/3/)