# How to move cursor to next/previous word in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, textarea

How would you move the cursor to the next or previous word in a textarea using Javascript? I'm trying to replicate the Emacs commands "forward one word" and "back one word" in an HTML textarea.

I can get the current caret/cursor position using [rangyinputs](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs), but I'm not yet sure how to efficiently move to the next word without using various splits that could be slow on very long pieces of text.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `setCaretToTextEnd()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9406052/1460839) and `.selectRange()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841121/1460839). The following functions use Emacs style caret positions, and is more efficient than looping through words.

```
function nextWord(input) {
  let currentCaretPosition = input.selectionStart;

  // -1 Because Emacs goes to end of next word.
  let nextWordPosition = input.value.indexOf(' ', currentCaretPosition) - 1;
  if (nextWordPosition < 0) {
    input.setCaretToTextEnd();
  } else {
    input.selectRange(nextWordPosition);
  }
}

function previousWord(input) {
  let currentCaretPosition = input.selectionStart;

  // +1 Because Emacs goes to start of previous word.
  let previousWordPosition = input.value.lastIndexOf(' ', currentCaretPosition) + 1;
  if (previousWordPosition < 0) {
    input.selectRange(0);
  } else {
    input.selectRange(previousWordPosition);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4og712t/1/). I used functions from [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area) to change position of cursor.

```
function nextWord(input) {
    var words = input.value.split(" "),
        index = 0;
    for (var i in words) {
        var word = words[i];
        if (index+word.length >= input.selectionStart) {
            setCaretToPos(input, index+word.length+1);
            break;
        }
        index += word.length+1;
    }
}
function previousWord(input) {
    var words = input.value.split(" ").reverse(),
        index = input.value.length;
    for (var i in words) {
        var word = words[i];
        if (index+1 <= input.selectionStart) {
        setCaretToPos(input, index-word.length);
            break;
        }
        index -= word.length+1;
    }
}
```