# Set focus to the end of input tag by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, input

Salut. i have some problem with javascript..

I made translate script, that allows Georgian users type Georgian by Latin alphabet. 
So, when i manipulate on **input tag**, i can't set focus to the end of the text.. correctly, cursor is in the end of text but if text is much bigger than input tag, it must **scroll automatically and must not hide.**

here's code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".geok").geokbd();
});
$.fn.geokbd = function() {
    symbols = "abgdevzTiklmnopJrstufqRySCcZwWxjh";
    this.relatedCheckbox = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"geokbd\" />").attr('checked', true);
    $(this).after(this.relatedCheckbox);
    $(this).keypress(
        function(e) {
            if ((e.charCode) == 96) {
                if ($(this).next('input').attr('checked')) {
                    $(this).next('input').attr('checked', false);
                } else {
                    $(this).next('input').attr('checked', true);
                }
                    return false;
                }
                if ($(this).next('input').attr('checked')) {
                    if ((index = symbols.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) >= 0) {
                        ret = String.fromCharCode(index + 4304);
                            this.focus();
                            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop, 
                            start = this.selectionStart, 
                            end = this.selectionEnd;

                            var value = this.value.substring(0, start)  + ret + this.value.substring(end,this.value.length);

                            this.value = value;
                            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
                            this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + ret.length;

                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }
        );
}
```

thanks

Comment: As i understand reason is that i manually insert Value for input element and i return false on keypress. If i return true, everythings ok but unnecessary symbols.

Answer (score 0):

get the `id` of last input tag and replave `name` with that id , below is basic logic

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus()
{
     document.getElementById("name").focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">
  <form>
       Name: <input type="text" id="name" size="30"><br />
       Surname: <input type="text" id="surname" size="30"> 
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Read the whole question, not only the title.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
function doSetCaretPosition (oField, iCaretPos) {
    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
        // Set focus on the element
        oField.focus ();
        // Create empty selection range
        var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
        // Move selection start and end to 0 position
        oSel.moveStart ('character', -oField.value.length);
        // Move selection start and end to desired position
        oSel.moveStart ('character', iCaretPos);
        oSel.moveEnd ('character', 0);
        oSel.select ();
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart == '0') {
        oField.selectionStart = iCaretPos;
        oField.selectionEnd = iCaretPos;
        oField.focus ();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourElement").focus();
    doSetCaretPosition(document.getElementById("yourElement"),999);
});
```

(source : http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-74982.html )

Comment: i dont want to set focus on document.ready.. i want it on keypress. so, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers from

[Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

For example, you can use

```
        <input id="search" type="text" value="mycurrtext" size="30" 
        onfocus="this.value = this.value;" name="search"/>
```

Or you can use the JQuery plugin:  PutCursorAtEnd. The author even posted the source code there and I tested that this works for Opera.