# jQuery Textbox Cursor to end of Text?

Tags: jquery, textbox, focus

I am trying to use jQuery to basically replace the cursor at the end of the text in a textbox AFTER the user hits "enter"

I have the "enter" part working - but I've no idea how [after the enter part] - I can get the cursor to return to the end of the inputted text inside the textbox ?

i.e. at the moment, when the user hits enter - the cursor goes to a new line and I want it to basically go to the end of the current text?

Some code:

```
jQuery('#textbox').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            ... submits textbox
        }
        jQuery(this).focus(function() {
          var val = this.input.value; //store the value of the element
          this.input.value = ''; //clear the value of the element
          this.input.value = val; //set that value back.  
        )};    
});
```

Comment: Do you have a link or some samples we can look at? My first guess would be some way of preventing default, but I can't be sure.

Comment: i found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element - but not sure it helps ?

Comment: I meant something that *you've* done. Your question makes it sounds like you've written some actual code. Can we see *that*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to prevent the 'enter' key from creating a newline, you can use `preventDefault` to block it.

```
$("textarea").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eX5gf/)

If you really want enter pressed *anywhere* in the input to go to the end of the input, you can also reset the value which will always put the cursor at the end of the input:

```
$("textarea").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        var val = $(this).val();       
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).val(val);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: hey dave - great thanks this works :) I think just the preventDefault(); is ok for me but +1 for adding the second as well.