# How to place cursor at the end of text in div tag with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's a lot of solution around here

to place cursor at the end of text for `input` or `textbox` tag.

[Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

[jQuery Textbox Cursor to end of Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953192/jquery-textbox-cursor-to-end-of-text?lq=1)

[jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area?rq=1)

Currently, I use `div` tag with `contenteditable = "true"` instead of using `input` or `textbox` tag.

Unfortunately, even I replace  `val` to `text` to make the code work, none of them works as intended.

Any thought?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems all of the referenced posts answer your question?

Comment: They related, and they works only for `input` or `textbox` tag not for `div` tag with `contenteditable = "true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a similar question, and this seems unbelievably complicated.

[Set cursor position on contentEditable <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div?rq=1)

Although someone claims something, I used,
Zane Claes's answer, and works as intended.

```
$.fn.focusEnd = function() {
    $(this).focus();
    var tmp = $('<span />').appendTo($(this)),
        node = tmp.get(0),
        range = null,
        sel = null;

    if (document.selection) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(node);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    tmp.remove();
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After all solutions from above question, I gave one solution. Enter the text and press enter the cursor move to end of text,

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/eX5gf/58/)

Try with,

```
$("div").keypress(function (event) {

    if (event.which == '13') {

        var val = $(this).text();    

        $(this).text('');
        $(this).text(val);
        setCursorToEnd($(this).get(0))

        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
function setCursorToEnd(ele)
  {

    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(ele, 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    ele.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact, I've tried this code prior to this question, and had an error `Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist` for `range`.

Comment: In fact, yes, and haven't seen it focused or cursror location.

Comment: Are you pressed the enter buttion ?. You need to press enter button.

Comment: Anyway, this code does not work for my project. I will post alternative answer by myself now.