# How to set the cursor position at the end of a string in a text field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, cursor, textfield

I am using jQuery 1.6 and I have a text field for which I would like the cursor to be positioned at the end of the string\text after the field receives focus. Is there a trivial or easy to do this?

At this time I am using the following code:

```
$jQ('#css_id_value').focus(function(){
    this.select();
});
$jQ('css_id_value').focus();
```

Comment: Checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#foo').focus(function() {
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
        this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length, this.value.length);
    } else if (this.createTextRange) {
        // IE
        var range = this.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveStart('character', this.value.length);
        range.moveEnd('character', this.value.length);
        range.select();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hn8EY/

```
$("input").mouseup(function(){
    this.selectionStart = this.value.length;
    this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
});
```

that should do it.

and alternatively (because I have no clue what your after here :P)

```
$("input").mouseup(function(){
    if($(this).not(".c").length) {
        this.selectionStart = this.value.length;
        this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
        $(this).addClass("c");
    }
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("c");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
var FieldInput = $('#fieldName');
var FldLength= FieldInput.val().length;
FieldInput.focus();
FieldInput[0].setSelectionRange(FldLength, FldLength);
```

Hope this help for you

Comment: doesn't do anything :|