# jQuery: How to focus on input text field such that the cursor is placed at the end of the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, textinput, cursor-position

Consider the following example: ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wVyD2/))

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<div>Click here to set focus</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("input").val("Hello");
    $("div").click(function() {
        $("input").focus();
    });
});
```

When the `div` is clicked, the cursor positioned at the beginning of the text: `|Hello`.

How could I set the cursor at the end of the text: `Hello|` ?

Comment: its already setting to end of the string maybe cause of your browser i am using firefox and I just tried your demo link and it works. When i click the div , the cursor setting end of hello

Comment: even for me, with chrome, it comes at the end of string.

Comment: It works in chrome also. Unless I position the cursor to somewhere else, of course, but by default it goes to the end.

Comment: for IE the cursor is positoned at the beginning of the text

Comment: I use Firefox 6.0.2, and when I click on the `div` in the example above, the cursor is positioned at the beginning of `Hello`.

Comment: In Chrome 14.0, the cursor is positioned at the end though.

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/PutCursorAtEnd

Comment: You don't need a goddamn plugin for everything!

Comment: Here's the [plugin code](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.putCursorAtEnd.1.0.js.txt), take what you need and implement it the right way.

Comment: I think using the plugin is a good idea, because if the plugin is updated (for example to cater for new browsers that don't exist yet) then you can easily update all your sites that use the plugin.

Comment: Up until that time, your users have to make tonnes of extra http requests to download the tonnes of plugins you've pointed to. All because you couldn't write a simple function yourself. If the plugin code gets updated, update your own damn code.

Comment: You could write some code to concatenate your plugins into one file that gets minified and compressed, which solves your issue of multiple downloads... and also your issue with wanting people to write code

Comment: Link to plugin is now broken.

Comment: Not tried it out, but this seems thorough: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [selectionStart](http://parentnode.org/javascript/working-with-the-cursor-position/).