# jquery trigger focus and cursor movement

Tags: jquery, triggers, focus, setfocus

Is there any way to trigger the `focus()` event on a `<textarea>` element and put the mouse cursor at the end of the text which is inside the textarea?

thx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: yep sorry didn't founded before that question :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was going to close as duplicate, but the other one doesn't cover how to trigger the focus.

See: [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element) for how to put the mouse cursor at the end

And to trigger the focus, you just need `$('#foo').focus()` or `$('#foo').trigger('focus')`