# Focus on textfield and place marker at end of text with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following js look for the textfield q in queryform and focus it:

**js:**

`if($("#queryform").length){
        document.queryform.q.focus();
    }`

**html:**

```
<form id="queryform" name="queryform" action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="q" /></form>
```

**current function**

In chrome: textfield is found and focused and text is highlighted

In FF and IE: textfield is focused and marker is placed at the back

**wanted function**

Same in all browsers: textfield is focused, text not highlighted, marked at the end of the text

**jquery**

I already use jquery on the site so a neat jquery solution is preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this soloution:

[Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

The first soloution didnt work, but his script did, see http://jsfiddle.net/WcGLP/

```
(function($)
{
    jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function()
    {
    return this.each(function()
    {
        $(this).focus()

        // If this function exists...
        if (this.setSelectionRange)
        {
        // ... then use it
        // (Doesn't work in IE)

        // Double the length because Opera is inconsistent about whether a carriage return is one character or two. Sigh.
        var len = $(this).val().length * 2;
        this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
        }
        else
        {
        // ... otherwise replace the contents with itself
        // (Doesn't work in Google Chrome)
        $(this).val($(this).val());
        }

        // Scroll to the bottom, in case we're in a tall textarea
        // (Necessary for Firefox and Google Chrome)
        this.scrollTop = 999999;
    });
    };
})(jQuery);
```