# How to place the cursor at the end of text input?

Tags: jquery, input, focus, cursor

```
$(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('#myInput').focus();
  });
})
```

The above will focus `<input type="text" id="myInput" />`, but how can I place the cursor at the end of a filled input?

This has been asked before but not solved. selectionStart was mentioned but seems to work for textareas only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php) looks like it might help you.