# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
**While running apps in chrome browser I'm getting
    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` but in IE it is working fine.
    I this line m getting issues"   if (elem.addEventListener)   "
    if (elem.addEventListener)
    elem -->myForm
    elem is parameter replaced by myForm variable.
```

I have added javascript code as well as HTML code.
    Please explain with solution for below code.**

```
    function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    function listenHandler(e) {
    var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    if (ret === false) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    return(ret);
    }

    function attachHandler() {
    var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
    if (ret === false) {
    window.event.returnValue = false;
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    return(ret);
    }

    if (elem.addEventListener) {**here is issue**
    elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
    } else {
    elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
    }
    }

    var myForm = document.getElementById("1form");

    addEvent( myForm, 'submit', function() { return validateForm(document.nextForm, document.1form); } );
```

**Here is HTML code which I think can help, if any required then let me Know.The HTML code code contain java code, u can see <% and %> here i am inserting java code**

```
<html >
<script language="javascript"></script>
<%   java code%>
<body ><table >
//
</table>

<form action="someAction" method="post"
onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm(document.someForm)"  >

</form>

<% 
java code
if (condition ) {%>
<form name="1form" target="1target"  >
<% 
} else {
%>
<form name="1form"    target="2target"  >
<% }%>
</form>

</body>    
<script>
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
function listenHandler(e) {
var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
if (ret === false) {
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
}
return(ret);
}

function attachHandler() {
var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
if (ret === false) {
window.event.returnValue = false;
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
}
return(ret);
}

if (elem.addEventListener) {
elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
} else {
elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
}
}    

var myForm = document.getElementById("prsregistrationform");

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: elem is element variable

Comment: // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149963/adding-event-listener-cross-browser code is taken from here

Comment: Try `console.log(elem);` at the beginning of your function to see what `elem` actually is.

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: var myForm = document.getElementById("1form");                                    addEvent( myForm, 'submit', function().........                                                           elem is myForm=form id

Comment: Seems like document.getElementById("1form") returns null. What is your html?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Comment: @SarahElan it return null in this line where i commented  "if (elem.addEventListener) "

Comment: `var myForm = document.getElementById("1form")` assigns null to myForm, which you then pass to addEvent as elem. Then when you check elem.addEventListener, you are trying to access the addEventListener property of null, like the error message says. So the question is why does document.getElementById("1form") return null? Edit your question and post the html where 1form is defined.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366781/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null