# Javascript & HTML : get the first value of an array row

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this Javascript function which "alerts" the content of a clicked cell, wherever I click on my HTML array :

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
if (table != null) {
   for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
         table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {tableText(this);};
   }
}
function tableText(tableCell) {alert(tableCell.innerHTML);}
```

My goal is returning only the value of the first cell of the clicked row (I've tried to manage it but I'm a newbie in Javascript...). Thanks in advance !

Comment: One approach would be to bind an event listener to the table like this: `table.addEventListener('click',function(e){`…`})` and in that callback function going up the DOM tree from `e.target` (i. e. `e.target.parentNode.parentNode…` until you hit a `<tr>`) and then of that `tr` returning `.children[0]`. It depends on whether you want to use a loop or jQuery or other libraries.

Comment: use jQuery in combination with https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ and https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use jquery

```
$("#tableID tbody tr").click(function() {
    var first_td = $(this).closest("tr") // Finds the closest <tr> 
        .find("td:first") // Finds the first <td>
        .text(); // Gets its text. 
    console.log("Selected first_td is  : ", first_td);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting first child from parent element. Just use `tableCell.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML` instead `tableCell.innerHTML`

Comment: What if one layer of `parentNode` isn’t sufficient?

Comment: Of course there was the suggestion that the cell is already in the row element, otherwise you need look over parent nodes until it reaches the <tr> node.

Answer (score 1):

```
function tableText(tableCell) {
    alert(tableCell.parentElement.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Fiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/5z8q30jt/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use jquery:

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/qdrOev

```
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149963/adding-event-listener-cross-browser
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            return(fn.call(elem, window.event));   
        });
    }
}

var table = document.getElementById('test');
addEvent(table, 'click', function(e){
  var node = e.srcElement;
  while(node.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' && node.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  if(node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr') {
    var td = node.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
    alert(td.innerHTML)
  }

});
```