# Primefaces inputtext focus at the end of the text

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here a snippet of my JSF:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" var="tab" value="#{data.tabs}" widgetVar="tabViewWidget"
                activeIndex="#{data.newActiveTabIndex}">

                <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{logic.closeTab}" />

                <p:tab title="#{tab.content.title != null ? tab.content.title : '&amp;lt;new&amp;gt;'}"
                    closable="#{tab.isClosable and data.tabs.size() > 2}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{tab.id} Test" />

                    <p:focus rendered="#{data.componentIdToFocus != null}" for="#{data.componentIdToFocus}" />

                    <p:inputText id="test" value="#{tab.content.title}">
                        <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{logic.setFocusingComponent}" update=":form:tabView" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </p:tab>

            </p:tabView>
```

The intent is that there is a textfield within each tab that updates the title of the tab while writing.
The given snippet works except that p:focus places the cursor at the beginning of the text that is already written. I want the cursor to be placed at the end of the text already written. So that a user can type and while he/she is typing the title adapts automatically.

I hope my case is clear.
Does anybody have a solution for that?

Best regards,
Florian

Comment: Give an id to your tab, and change update part of the ajax to ":form:tabView:tabIndex". This should only update the tab title and you wouldn't lose the focus for your text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `onfocus="this.value=this.value"` trick to "deselect" the value so that the cursor automagically ends up in the end of the value. This should work as good for the `<p:inputText>` as it basically generates just a `<input type="text">` element.

```
<p:inputText ... onfocus="this.value=this.value" />
```

#### See also:

- [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I wouldn't use ajax and such on keyup event and an update of the whole tabview. This seems to be quite expensive. I'd rather do a simple HTML DOM traversion and manipulation here by JS/jQuery.

E.g.

```
<p:inputText ... onkeyup="updateTitle(this)" />
```

with

```
function updateTitle(inputInTab) {
    var panelId = $(inputInTab).closest(".ui-tabs-panel").attr("id");
    $("a[href='#" + panelId + "']").text(inputInTab.value);
}
```