# Set mouse cursor at the end of the block of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

`$(id).focus();` sets the cursor position to the beginning of an input box, but I'd like to place it at the end of the text, in the last row and at the last position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").focus(function(){
            if (this.setSelectionRange)
            {
            var len = $(this).val().length;
            this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
            }
            else
            {
            $(this).val($(this).val());
            }

    });

    $("#search").focus();
    });
```

[Demo with input](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dkwg/3/)

[Demo with textarea](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dkwg/2/)

Because `setSelectionRange` is not supported by all browsers. So the best solution is to combine `setSelectionRange` with `$(this).val($(this).val());`. For more information, check out: [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Comment: it sets the position at start, but I want it at the end of text

Comment: @nrsharma: checkout the demo. I tested with Chrome and it works

Comment: it's not working with <textarea>. It's setting the curosr at the beginning.

Comment: @nrsharma: i think the problem is with the browser. `setSelectionRange` as in Ishan Jain's answer is also the solution. But `setSelectionRange` is not supported by all browsers. I think the best way is to combine this solution with `setSelectionRange`

Comment: well, you are right setSelectionRange is not working with all browsers.

Comment: @nrsharma: added a demo with textarea.

Comment: @Khanh: it's nice solution, but "setSelectionRange" working in all major browsers(FF, IE and Chrome).

Comment: @Ishan Jain:check browser compatibility in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange

Comment: @Khanh: Yes, you are right. But i checked it in IE10, Chrome27  and it's working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setSelectionRange` for this

My code -

HTML -

```
<textarea rows="8" id="txt1" style="width:400px;" >Hello Hello Hello Hello</textarea>
```

Jquery -

```
var input = $("#txt1");
var len = input.val().length;
input[0].focus();
input[0].setSelectionRange(len, len);
```

Try -

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j6yVq/2/)

Comment: You should post the code you're actually using **here** as well, not just a jsFiddle