# Move cursor to the right end side after tying or focusing a textbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, cursor, right-align

I have a textbox which accepts numeric values, i want the cursor to be moved on the right end side when user focus on the textbox or types anything in it.

***HTML Markup***

```
<input type="text" class="numericBox" tabindex="0" value="0.00">
```

***CSS***

```
.numericBox{
 text-align:right;
}
```

## Fiddle Demo

I have tried `direction:rtl` property of CSS, but i think it's not for the same. Any suggestion with jQuery or pure CSS/CSS3 will be apreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify dir attribute is rtl

```
 <input type="text" name="user" dir="rtl" />
```

Comment: By using dir="rtl" it will create the problem if you add '.' or space. The cursor will be shown on left most side.