# Cursor position to end of string in listgird textbox?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

> Is there any way by which, i can set the cursor position to end of string in listgird textbox.
>   Example :
>   Enter website name, once user click on cell of listgird its will display 'http://' now i want that my cursor position to the end of string.>

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: @Reddy The question is related to GWT or SmartGWT?

Comment: @RAS related to SmartGWT

Comment: @Reddy I don't think there's any such built-in functionality. But let's see for some more answers.

Answer (score 1):

it is quite easy:

```
    TextBox yourBox = new TextBox();
    root.add(yourBox);
    yourBox.setValue("AMSTERDAM");
    yourBox.setFocus(true);
    yourBox.setCursorPos(yourBox.getValue().length());
```

sometimes you lose anyway the focus while rendering the complete component. If this happens you can try to put the setFocus in a scheduleDeferred-Command, it means, after the rendering process of the browser is done, the code in execute() will be executed. So you can be sure, that no other component will get also a focus, and your component lose it again.

```
    final TextBox yourBox = new TextBox();
    root.add(yourBox);
    yourBox.setValue("AMSTERDAM");
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand()
    {
        @Override
        public void execute()
        {
            yourBox.setFocus(true);
            yourBox.setCursorPos(yourBox.getValue().length());
        }
    });
```

Comment: im sorry..but my question was about ListGrid not about TextBox. ListGrid doesnt have the method setCursorPos().