# How can I focus an input onload without selecting the value on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to focus an input field without selecting the text in it. I want cursor to be on the end and ready to add more text.

This is my input field:

```
<input type="text" name="change" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>" autofocus>
```

P.S - autofocus select the text.

Comment: Do you allow jQuery solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for that:

```
<input type="text" name="change" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>" autofocus onfocus="this.value = this.value;">
```

Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

If you know jQuery, then you can do like this:

```
var input = $('input[name="change"'),
    strLen = input.val().length;
input.val(input.val());
input.focus();
input[0].setSelectionRange(strLen, strLen);
```

You can find out more information about `Input.setSelectionRange` from MDN **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange)**

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3HhC/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc45u/1/

```
<input id="inp1" value="abcdefg" /> 
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('inp1').focus();document.getElementById('inp1').value = document.getElementById('inp1').value;" value="FOCUS" />
```