# Move cursor to end input with jquery masked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, maskedinput

I'm using jQuery masked input plugin, and when I take the focus of the field and return the focus (blur, focus) the cursor back to the beginning, need to always leave the cursor at the end but I can not.

```
$('#id_origin_zipcode').bind('focus', $.proxy(this.moveCursorToEnd, this));

moveCursorToEnd: function(e){
    var value = $('#id_origin_zipcode').val();
    $('#id_origin_zipcode').val(value);

},
```

Comment: Can you show what code you have so far? It would be very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Answer (score 2):

You can set selectionStart and selectionEnd to the value length. e.g.

```
<input type="text" onFocus="this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;" />
```