# On load set blinking cursor on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor

I am working on a text editor where I am appending an iframe over textarea for text styling. But my problem is that I have to make the cursor blink on the iframe body when I am trying to open the editor.I am very new to this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('#iframeId').focus();
```

To set focus at end of text, see this -

[Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Comment: Thanks it worked. One more thing, can you please tell me how to blink it at the end of a text?