# set focus of textfield to the last character entered in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In an HTML file, I have a text field and a button. When the button is pressed, text is added to the to text field via plain JavaScript.

HTML:

```
please input : <input id="city" type="text" name="city" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction()
{
   var a=document.getElementById("city").value ;
   document.getElementById("city").value = a;
}
```

How to set the focus of the text field to the last entered character by using only plain JavaScript, without jQuery or other libraries?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please take look on this.
 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: not working solution for me

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction()
{
   document.getElementById('city').focus()
}
```