# How to focus textarea at last in asp webfrom using code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on web page in which I have to save typed content in textarea after 10 sec of last key press, once data is saved I am using **Focus()** to focus again in text area because it is focusing out.

```
txtClientArea.Focus();
```

Problem is that it always focus in start of text area so each time I need to either click in the end of content of press **End key**. I am not using .cs file as a back end but writing code is script tag.

```
<script type="text/C#" language="c#" runat="server">

//.........

</script>
```

is there any way to focus at the end using code.
I have tried using js in code but closing tag of script conflict with c# script tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line with `txtClientArea.Focus();` in your code, it works for me.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Show Windows" + new Random().Next().ToString(), "var lsArea = document.getElementById('" + txtClientArea.ClientID + "'); lsArea.focus();var val = lsArea.value; lsArea.value = ''; lsArea.value=val;", true);
```