# React autoFocus sets cursor to beginning of input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a controlled input that has a value initially showing. 
I have set that input to autoFocus but the cursor appears at the beginning of the input when I am wanting it to appear at the end. I understand this might be because the autoFocus is added before the value is but I'm not 100% sure.

What would be the best way to accomplish the cursor initializing at the end of the input field?

```
var Test = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
           teamId: 'fdsfds'
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
                <input type="text" autoFocus value={this.state.teamId} onChange={this.setTeamId} />
        );
    },

    setTeamId: function(event) {
        this.setState({ teamId: id });
    },

});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/34486/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One solution:

```
<input
  type="text"
  autoFocus
  value={this.state.teamId}
  onChange={this.setTeamId}
  onFocus={function(e) {
    var val = e.target.value;
    e.target.value = '';
    e.target.value = val;
  }}
/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3s05zz4/1/

Adaptation of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345915/1589521

Comment: Perhaps extract the logic out in another method as is the case with other props? Works perfectly fine, btw.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good solution because it moves the cursor at the end not just for the auto focus but also when user focuses the input by clicking into it later. Not good UX.

Comment: I just incremented the likes from 42 to 43. Maybe I should have left it at 42.

Answer (score 8):

This actually works:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const input = this.input;
    const length = input.value.length;
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(length, length);
}

render() {
   return (
       <input ref={ref => this.input = ref} ... >
   )
}
```

PS. If you need to support IE8 and below you'll need to use IE-specific checks.

Comment: **TIP:** No need for `length` *const*, you can do `input.setSelectionRange(Infinity, Infinity)`

Comment: @vsync your tip did not work for me - the caret was placed at the beginning. Had to specify length as in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This way the text of the input will be selected, ready to edit

```js
<input
  type="text"
  defaultValue="Untitled"
  autoFocus
  onFocus={e => e.currentTarget.select()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the input value inside componentDidMount seems to do the trick, but it feels like a hack:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    this.inputElement.value = this.state.teamId;
},

render: function() {
    var that = this;
    return <input ref={function(ref){that.inputElement = ref;}} type="text" autoFocus value={this.state.teamId} onChange={this.setTeamId} />;
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yuk13tuu/

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript:

```
private inputDOM: HTMLInputElement | null;

public componentDidMount() {
    if (this.inputDOM != null) {
        this.inputDOM.value = '';
        this.inputDOM.value = this.state.newRegionName;
    }
}

public render() {
    return <input ref={(ref: HTMLInputElement | null) => this.inputDOM = ref} type="text" autoFocus={true} value={this.state.inputValue} />;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the html attribute `autofocus` doesn't take any parameters to specify where the cursor should start. See [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autofocus).

Sitepoint has a great tutorial explaining your options for [setting cursor position from within an input box](http://www.sitepoint.com/jqueryhtml5-input-focus-cursor-positions/).

As for the reacty side of things, you'll simply put your jQuery (or other cursor related code) in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.