# Set focus in texbox at last char in an asp.net web page using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, focus

I have a textbox in an asp.net web page. In case of postback, I need to set focus on last char in this texbox. how can I do this using c# without using anything like jQueries..
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a variation of the solution proposed in [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element):

```
void btnPostBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFocus.Attributes["onfocus"] = "var value = this.value; this.value = ''; this.value = value; onfocus = null;";
    txtFocus.Focus();
}
```

Comment: It didnt work. focus is going back to the textbox but the cursor is not at last character in this textbox

Comment: You must be testing on Firefox. I had tested on IE and Chrome. I will see if there is a way to do the same in Firefox.

Comment: Exactly!!! im working on firefox, i tried it on chrome and it worked but unfortunatly i need it on firefox

Comment: I made a correction to the code. You can try again.

Comment: You're welcome! I made an additional correction, to avoid some misbehavior when using the form after the postback. Setting the focus to another control and putting it back in the TextBox always pushed the caret at the end, which was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code like below :

```
asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" TabIndex="1">
asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" TabIndex="2">
```

```
   protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["event_controle"] = ((TextBox)sender);
   }

   protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["event_controle"] = ((TextBox)sender);
   }

   protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           if (Session["event_controle"] != null)
           {
               TextBox controle =(TextBox) Session["event_controle"];
               controle.Focus();
           }
       }
       catch ()
       {
       }
   }
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Can you please explain your idea?