# How to set cursor at the end of a 'contenteditable' span element that contains other tags and text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set focus at the end of a span element,that content editable set  true and it contains other span tags and normal text.

I was used  range object option(`rangeObj.setStart (textNode, 1);rangeObj.setEnd (textNode, 2);`) but it shows error.

Comment: What error does it throw ? Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at <anonymous>:1:7** i got this error @PirateX