# How to focus on the end of input after changing value during focus

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm building an autocomplete feature. Everything works as expected except when I reach the end of the input. When I change the value of the input, programatically, the input doesn't scroll/focus on the cursor until I type something.

I tried doing something like this on `componentDidUpdate` and it worked, but besides being a bit "dirty" I don't want to use the `onBlur` because I'm closing the autocomplete popup on this event.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.refInput.input.selectionStart = this.refInput.input.selectionEnd = this.state.value.length;
    this.refInput.input.blur();
    this.refInput.input.focus();
}, 1);
```

How can I achieve this, specially without a `setTimeout`? If I do it without the `setTimeout` it doesn't work.

Comment: check out this stackoverflow answer [js focus end of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Comment: None of the solutions given worked sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) Hook

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

//
//

useEffect(()=>{
    this.refInput.input.selectionStart = this.refInput.input.selectionEnd =  this.state.value.length;
    this.refInput.input.blur();
    this.refInput.input.focus();
 },[this.state.value, this.refInput.input.selectionStart, this.refInput.input.selectionEnd])
```

Comment: I'm using a class component for this. Cannot use useEffect. Also I don't want to use blur as the event is used for other things that I don't want necessarily to trigger every time the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

I made it worked. Unfortunately it is not very pretty. I still need to use the `blur` and `setTimeout` events.

```
onBlur = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.refInput.input !== document.activeElement) {
      console.log(this.refInput.input.selectionEnd);
      this.setState({ helperVisible: false });
      this.props.clearAutoComplete();
    }
  }, 1);
};

(...)

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  const { value } = this.state;
  if (prevState.value !== value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.refInput.input.selectionStart = this.refInput.input.selectionEnd = this.state.value.length;
      this.refInput.input.blur();
      this.refInput.input.focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

If anyone has any ideia how to improve this it would be great. Otherwise I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below should grab the element. focus on it. then move the selection range to the end of the current value. This abides by the desire to avoid blur().
CAVEAT: sometimes it doesn't seem to properly fire in this snippet and in codepen..

```js
(function () {
 const el = document.getElementById('dataList'),
    val = 'this is my value',
  len = val.length;
 el.focus();
  el.value = val;
 setTimeout(function () { el.setSelectionRange(len, len); }, 100);
})();
```

```html
<input id="dataList">
```

Comment: I've tried it and unfortunately it didn't work for me :(