# How to focus end of the text in <code> tag in HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, cursor-position

I m trying to reformat some text inside an HTML code tag, via onkeypress event. But after text changing, the cursor goes the start position. I must keep the current position of the cursor.

To prevent this problem I found this;

```
this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
```

from:
[Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

But I see, it works only for input elements :(

```
<code contenteditable="true" id="editor"  onkeypress="CreateStyle()">
  select * <span style="color:blue">from</span> SomeTable</code>
```

how can I play with cursor position inside a code tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) to set the selection

```js
const codeNode = document.getElementById('editor');
const range = document.createRange();
const selection = window.getSelection();

range.setStartAfter(codeNode.lastChild);
range.setEndAfter(codeNode.lastChild);

selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

```html
<code contenteditable="true" id="editor"  onkeypress="CreateStyle()">
  select * <span style="color:blue">from</span> SomeTable</code>
```

Comment: This code sends the cursor end, but what if we want to keep current position index, not to end?

Comment: You could save the position in a variable or element attribute when focus is gone and retrieve it when focus comes back