# How I can set focus on the element when I am setting it to content editable in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using the contentEditable attribute of Angular 6 for editing the content of the element (in the ngFor)

How I can set focus on a tag element when it's contentEditable attribute is true?

```
<div class="tag" *ngFor="let tag of tags">
   <span [contentEditable]="underUpdateTagId==tag.id" [textContent]="tag.title 
    (input)="tag.title=$event.target.textContent">
   </span>
   <span *ngIf="underUpdateTagId!=tag.id" class="edit text-info" (click)="beforeEdit(tag)">
         <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
   </span>
   <span *ngIf="underUpdateTagId==tag.id" class="update text-success" (click)="editTag(tag)">
         <i class="fas fa-check save"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="delete text-danger" (click)="delete(tag)">
         <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

The user interface:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ViewChildren` to get a hold of all the spans, by placing a template reference, pick up the `span` that is selected and set the focus to the element.

So I suggest adding template reference and in your `beforeEdit()` pass the index of the tag (we get it from ngFor), so we can refer to it when we want to place the focus on the field:

```html
<!-- add template reference in below span tag --->
<span [contentEditable]="underUpdateTagId==tag.id" ... #spans>
<!-- pass index as from ngFor iteration to beforeEdit() -->
<span *ngIf="underUpdateTagId!=tag.id" class="edit text-info" (click)="beforeEdit(tag, i)">
<!-- more code --->
```

In the component we refer to `spans`, the template reference. And when clicked upon specify that the span with the index passed should be focused:

```ts
@ViewChildren("spans") spans: QueryList<ElementRef>;
underUpdateTagId = null;

beforeEdit(tag, index) {
  this.underUpdateTagId = tag.id;
  // wait a tick
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.spans.toArray()[index].nativeElement.focus();
  });
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bd8gjv)**

PS, this sets the focus in the beginning, you might want it at the end, maybe this question can help you with it if that is the case: [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)