# jQuery focus() to set focus in the end of the input

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery focus to set focus on a newly created input.

It works well, but the focus is set in the beginning of the input even though there is a pre-defined text. How can I place it after the text?

```js
$('.button').on('click', function () {
$('.container').html('<input type="text" class="newinput" value="word">');
$('.newinput').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button">create and focus</button>
<br />
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick would be to set focus and then set the value, if your scenario allows for that.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').html('<input type="text" class="newinput" value="">');
  $('.newinput').focus();
  $('.newinput').val("word");
})
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tqomec7d/

If that doesn't work for you, I think one of the answers here might help: [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setSelectionRange` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)

First, compute the length of the value in the input, then `setSelectionRange(length+1, length+1)`